# Split by words or operators with regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex, tokenize

How do I split

> -(ab | c) & d -> (d|c)&e <-> f

into an array

```
['-', '(', 'ab', '|', 'c', ')', '&', 'd', '->', '(', 'd', '|', 'c', ')', '&', 'e', '<->', 'f']
```

So in general, it should split the string into tokens. If two letters are combined into one word (e.g. `ab`), it should be considered as 1 token. I have the operators `-`, `(`, `)`, `|`, `&`, `->`, and `<->`.

It might be something like

```
var str = '-(ab | c) & d -> (d|c)&e <-> f';
var regex = /([-&\|()]|\w+)/;
str.split(regex);
```

but it doesn't include `->` and `<->`

Comment: well you do not include them in your reg exp...

Comment: I know. It is because I didn't know how to do so. If I just added them to `[-&\|`, it would also recognize just `<`, `-`, and `>`. and I am only interested in it to fully recognize `->` or `<->`

Comment: How about invalid inputs, e.g. `-(ab | c) @@@ & %%% d` ?

Comment: They should actually be eliminated. I didn't think of that. Actually, it should only allow letter combinations [A-Za-z]. So even numbers should be eliminated..

Comment: @Jamgreen - if you don't care about _anything_ else, you shouldn't use split. What about the order, scoping, nesting, operator precedence. This is not the way to parse tokens in any sane way. You should just match what you need and forget the rest. `->?|<->|[()|&]|[a-zA-Z]+`

Answer (score 4):

You can use this regex for splitting:

```js
var str = '-(ab | c) & d -> (d|c)&e <-> f';
var arr = str.split(/\s*(<?->|[-&|()]|\w+)\s*/).filter(Boolean)

console.log(arr)
//=> ["-", "(", "ab", "|", "c", ")", "&", "d", "->", "(", "d", "|", "c", ")", "&", "e", "<->", "f"]
```

**Breakup:**

```
\s*         # match 0 or more spaces
(           # group spart
   <?->     # match <-> or ->
   |        # OR
   [-&|()]  # match one of these symbols
   |        # OR
   \w+      # match 1 or more word chars
)           # group end
\s*         # match 0 or more spaces
```

Answer (score 2):

What about this?

```js
var string = '-(ab | c) & d -> (d|c)&e <-> f';
    
var result = string.match(/<->|->|[-()|&]|\w+/g);

console.log(result);
```

You can leverage the `[]` and `|` operators. See [JavaScript regex on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Comment: `()` etc are not special inside `[...]`, no need to escape them

Answer (score 2):

You may use a matching regex like

```
/<?->|[^\s\w]|\w+/g
```

where `[^\s\w]` matches any non-whitespace or non-word char, **assuming the strings do not contain rubbish**, else use

```
/<?->|[-()|&]|\w+/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jP3uM3/1) and a JS demo below:

```js
var re = /<?->|[-()|&]|\w+/g;
console.log("-(ab | c) & d -> (d|c)&e <-> f".match(re));
```

**Pattern details**:

- `<?->` - an optional `<` + `->`
- `|` - or
- `[^\s\w]` - a symbol other than whitespace and word char

  OR
- `[-()|&]` - one symbol, either a `-`, or `(`, `)`, `|`, or `&`
- `|` - or
- `\w+` - 1 or more word chars.

The `String#match` with a regex with a global modifier fetches an array of all the match values the regex could find in the input string.

Comment: With a matching approach, there is no need to apply an additional `.filter(Boolean)` operation.